# Can a &nbsp; have a CSS font-size?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I'm running a script that adds

```
&nbsp;
```

To a  tag in case my script does not return any text to fill a button element.

Problem is,  although the span has its space, the height of the elemeny is wrong.

**Question**
Is there a way to give font-size to a **nbsp;**? After all, it's a space, so it should respect the font-size being set on an element?

Comment: You shouldn't even use &nbsp; for that. Use CSS to set the dimensions of your button.

Comment: Without knowing your site/code, I am still pretty sure you should be approaching this from another angle. What is the reason to use the space when there is no result?

Comment: @dystroy: it's for a jQuery Mobile element and on Android, elements with parents that are `pos:absolute` and have empty children break form elements like selects. So `&nspb;` it must be. Of course I can set `min-height` but I was just wondering if a space can have a font-size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A no-break space, which can be represented in HTML as `&nbsp;`, is treated the same way as a printable character, just with an empty glyph. This means that font size affects it, and font size can be set on it like on any printable character. If you wish to make its font size differ from the font size of adjacent characters, then you need to wrap it in an element, e.g. `<span class=nobr>&nbsp;</span>`, and set `font-size` on it.

If a no-break space is the sole content of a `button` element, e.g. `<button ...>&nbsp;</button>`, then you can simply set `font-size` on that element. Note that the size of the button also depends on the `line-height` of its content as well as the rendering algorithm of buttons in the browser (which make the button larger than the size of its content).

Your real problem is probably very different and best addressed in a completely different way, but for the record, this was an answer to the question as asked.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to put something into a button to give it a size.

Here's how you can give a button a 20x20 size :

HTML :

```
 <button id=a></button>
```

CSS :

```
#a {
  weight:20px;
  height:20px;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/akarer/1/edit)

Comment: see my comment above and [here](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/3)

Comment: I think you mean width, in both the answer and the Demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

yes. empty space is also considered text and it will resize the button it fills in. **[check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WLZbR)**

html

```
<button class="button1">&nbsp;
```

css

```
.button1
{
    font-size: 22px;
}
```